# How to encode a string using zero width steganography

Tags: python, python-3.x, steganography

I am running Python 3.7.x and am trying to figure out how to encode a string, `{CTF-FLAG1}`, using zero width steganography.

I am using `zwsp-steg-py` to do so, but I do not know how to use this to encode text into other text, see below:

I want to encode `{CTF-FLAG1}` inside of the text `Now you see me, now you don't.` using zero width steganography.

I installed zwsp-steg-py and tried:

```
#coding=utf-8
import zwsp_steg
encoded = zwsp_steg.encode("{CTF-Flag1}", zwsp_steg.MODE_ZWSP)

decoded = zwsp_steg.decode(encode​​​​​​​‍‌‌‌​​​​​​‌​​‌​​​​​​​​‍‌‍‌​​​​​​​‌‍​​​​​​​​​‍‌‍‌​​​​​​‌‌​​​​​​​​​‌​‌‍‌​​​​​​‌​‍‌‌​​​​​​​‌‍‌‌)
print(decoded)
```

Yet, the result is:

```
C:\Users\jerry\Desktop>python decode.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "decode.py", line 5, in <module>
    decoded = zwsp_steg.decode(encoded)
  File "C:\Python367-64\lib\site-packages\zwsp_steg\steganography.py", line 72, in decode
    raise TypeError('Unknown encoding detected!')
TypeError: Unknown encoding detected!
```

I don't think I'm doing it right.

Comment: You have to pass a mode parameter to `.decode()` that matches the mode you used with `.encode()`.

Comment: Thanks @jasonharper, it decodes properly now. However, how can I actually turn the string "encoded" into something like `Now you see me, now you don't.` When I `print(encoded)` it prints a bunch of weird characters I cant paste here

Comment: that "weird text" is python escaping the zero-width characters and making them visible

Comment: Just concatenate it with the plain text; `.decode()` will ignore any normal characters you pass to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#coding=utf-8
import zwsp_steg
encoded = zwsp_steg.encode("{CTF-Flag1}", zwsp_steg.MODE_ZWSP)

decoded = zwsp_steg.decode(encode​​​​​​​‍‌‌‌​​​​​​‌​​‌​​​​​​​​‍‌‍‌​​​​​​​‌‍​​​​​​​​​‍‌‍‌​​​​​​‌‌​​​​​​​​​‌​‌‍‌​​​​​​‌​‍‌‌​​​​​​​‌‍‌‌, zwsp_steg.MODE_ZWSP)
print(decoded)

# example with string padding

encoded += "This is a test string"
print(encoded)
decoded_the_string = zwsp_steg.decode(encode​​​​​​​‍‌‌‌​​​​​​‌​​‌​​​​​​​​‍‌‍‌​​​​​​​‌‍​​​​​​​​​‍‌‍‌​​​​​​‌‌​​​​​​​​​‌​‌‍‌​​​​​​‌​‍‌‌​​​​​​​‌‍‌‌, zwsp_steg.MODE_ZWSP)
print(decoded_the_string)
```